# html5 required validation working great on browser but not phonegap app

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I am developing an app on phonegap (v 5.1.1) and using [phonegap app](http://app.phonegap.com/)  for testing locally on android. I have created a form in html and for validation purpose I've used required property. In browser (firefox, chrome) it is working fine as it should be, while on mobile it does not validate anything. and submits. Why is this happening ? Does html5 required supported on android.

```html
 <form id="LoginForm" action="">
   <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" required>
   <input type="password" name="pwd" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password" required>
   <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
   </form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What Android device / Android OS version are you running on?

Comment: Post your html full html

Comment: @SimonPrickett so I tried it on my friend's device having android v 5.1.1. and amazingly it is worked fine. so it means v 4.2 or lesser does not support it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running Android 4.2.2 and "required" / form validation isn't properly supported there until newer versions of Android.  caniuse.com has a good [matrix of support here](http://caniuse.com/#search=required).

To cover all Android versions, you can use "required" but don't rely on it and also defensively code for missing values in your JavaScript when the user submits the form.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting situation for iOS: now **it is supported in Safari Mobile** and when used with "Add to Home Screen" feature, however, once the app is built **using Cordova, validation is just ignored**.

Tested for `required` attribute, same device, almost the same `navigator.userAgent`:

Browser `navigator.userAgent`:

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15C107 Safari/604.1

Cordova app `navigator.userAgent`:

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15C107

Comment: I have come to the same conclusion - it works fine in Safari on desktop and iOS, but just doesn't work in Cordova. Very frustrating!